# C Passing struct by reference

Tags: c, pass-by-reference

I have the following struct which I want to pass by reference

```
typedef struct payload {
    char *payload;
    uint64_t payloadSize;
} Payload;
```

The following is the implementation for the method.

```
void parsePayload(const char *originalPayload, const int payloadSize, Payload *source) {    
    source->payloadLength = 5;
    source->payload = malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
    memcpy((void *)source->payload, originalPayload, 5);
}
```

with main function here, which i would like to pass the allocated object with the method modifying the content of the pointer

```
int main() {
    Payload *sourcePayload = malloc(sizeof(Payload));
    parsePayload("some random char", 16, &sourcePayload);
    Log("%d", sourcePayload->payloadSize);
}
```

However, there seems to be something wrong with the output when I log the payloadSize. Please advise what I have done wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Surely your compiler warnings are already telling you the mistake?

Comment: You declare `Payload *sourcePayload`, so `sourcePayload` is already type `Payload *` -- why take it's address? (only needed if passing `Payload **` to allow `realloc` within the function without returning a value) With gcc/clang add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` (at minimum) to your compiler string, for VS add `/W3`, and do not accept code until it compiles without warning. Let the compiler help you write better code. (it saves a lot of time in the log run)

Comment: As a side note, C only has pass by value. http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passbyref.html

Comment: the brownie points for not casting malloc are undone by casting the argument of memcpy

Answer (score 2):

`sourcePayload` has type `Payload *`, so `&sourcePayload` has type `Payload **`.  This is incompatible with what the function expects, and your compiler should have warned you about this.

Since `sourcePayload` already has a type that matches the function's parameter, just pass it directly.

```
parsePayload("some random char", 16, sourcePayload);
```

Also, be sure to `free(sourcePayload->payload)` then `free(sourcePayload)` at the end of `main`.

Comment: Just as a follow up question, if I free(sourcePayload), should I also free(sourcePayload->payload) prior to that?

Comment: @Dillon Yes, since it points to malloc'ed memory, you should first `free(sourcePayload->payload)` then `free(sourcePayload)`;